# Disproportionate windows in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Sorry for a noob question, but this is driving me nuts!

Some windows are of a disproportionate size in SQL SSMS and I need to reset them.  I recently replaced my old development laptop with a new one and I did a fresh install of Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, and SQL Server 2014 Enterprise.  When I initially installed management studio, my laptop's screen resolution was set at 2880x1620 with "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" set to 200%.  I've now docked my laptop and adjusted the built-in display to 1920x1080 and 100% and when I start management studio the dialog windows are huge!  They're so big in fact that many of the text boxes overlap each other.

Is there any way to reset SMS to factory defaults?

The login window:

[image]

The new db window:

[image]

Comment: this seems like a windows problem, only SSMS has problems ?

Comment: Yes, only SSMS has this problem.

Comment: Well, this is a Q&A web about programming, maybe you need to post this question in another stack exchange community, try superuser community.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into occurs because SSMS has not been optimized for High-DPI displays. You can try the recently released [SSMS November preview release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt238290.aspx) that has initial support for High-DPI displays.